# Add second function to a button and disable some classes

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress

I am searching  a way to get rid of some classes when browser window is under 1000pixels and add(toggle) new classes.

```
$( window ).on( 'resize', function( event ) {
    var windowSize = $( window ).width();
    if ( windowSize < 1000 ) {
        if ( $( '.site-header .search-form' ).hasClass( 'search-form--active' ) ) {
            $( '.site-header .search-form' ).removeClass( 'search-form--active' );
        } else if ( $( '.site-header .search-trigger' ).hasClass( 'search-form--active' ) ) {
            $( '.site-header .search-trigger' ).removeClass( 'search-form--active' );
        }
        $( '.search-trigger' ).click( function() {
            $( '.search-trigger' ).toggleClass( 'search-overlay.show' );
        } );
    }
} );
```

I am new to this,and i know my question might be a bit stupid,same as my code.
I don't know if you guys need anything more to help me ,if you do,just type what.Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: what about [@media](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media) rules?

Comment: Is there a way to toggle new class and remove old one on screen resize ,from same button with just media queries?If there is,can you give example?Sorry for stupid questions.

Comment: Well, what do you actually want to achieve? With media rules you can apply css rules that only apply on certain screen sizes. It doesn't change classes, but you don't necessarily have to, because you just define other css rules for the same classes with different resolutions. That's just one application. Checkout the examples on the link I've sent.

Comment: I want to connect 2 different styles to same button,and display them by restricting with with lower than 1000 px and above 1000px.How can i link my search icon to display Overlay search style only below 1000 px?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use CSS media queries instead of JS.

Simple example:

```js
var $btn  = $( 'button' );
var $lead = $( '.lead' );

$btn.on( 'click', function ( e ) {
  $lead.toggleClass( 'active' );
} );
```

```css
.lead {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
}
.active {
  background-color: #fc0;
}

@media ( min-width: 650px ) {
  .lead {
    font-size: 1rem;
  }
  .active {
    background-color: #aa0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="lead">
  Lateen sail yardarm swab dead men tell no tales warp heave down knave yawl aye man-of-war deadlights skysail me Cat o'nine tails jack ballast spirits stern Brethren of the Coast keel plunder aft interloper square-rigged pressgang. Crack Jennys tea cup reef sails deadlights long boat Pirate Round cackle fruit galleon keel heave to coxswain yo-ho-ho loot brig cog fathom jury mast hearties topgallant cable gabion league handsomely Jolly Roger spirits walk the plank. Pinnace boom measured fer yer chains loot Chain Shot jolly boat Buccaneer ho aft Yellow Jack rope's end matey sutler starboard spirits snow main sheet lookout Corsair ballast Pirate Round bilge cable Barbary Coast spike.
</p>
<p>
 Swing the lead lateen sail scuttle Blimey brig marooned warp belaying pin salmagundi Spanish Main yard crimp fire ship Sail ho splice the main brace gun starboard man-of-war code of conduct keel long clothes gibbet log grog blossom handsomely. Brig Yellow Jack landlubber or just lubber starboard crow's nest scuttle pinnace lugsail ho gangplank transom chase killick bounty mutiny maroon pirate Cat o'nine tails Jack Tar cutlass snow rigging matey splice the main brace Davy Jones' Locker. Wench overhaul quarterdeck crack Jennys tea cup Jack Ketch splice the main brace hulk grog driver starboard mizzen scurvy haul wind jack pink gally me strike colors walk the plank Barbary Coast transom hail-shot sloop Pirate Round long boat.
</p>
<button type="button" id="me">Click Me</button>
```

First part is represented by the `.active` class. It's purpose is to illustrate media queries and state based on user interaction. `.active` has two states, represented by a background color that changes at different viewport sizes. `.active` is also added/removed by clicking a button to show user interaction.

I've also changed the font size of the first paragraph independent of any page events in an attempt to illustrate how to make visual (state) changes with out JS.

Comment: I am sorry that ask right question.I want 1 button to display 2 different elements (divs) on 2 different screen sizen 1 below 1000px and 1 above 1000 px.Not just classes,but different elements.

Comment: @Dako my friend, you should have enough hints to go about now, don't you think ;) Try to fiddle a bit, and come back with specific questions about your code, we'll look at it again

Comment: yep you were right,after i set display:none to one of the classes other showed, THANKS !Both of you <3